# Resetting a task timer to 0 after method call

Tags: java, timer

This is something I have tried looking up but can't find a situation similar enough to what I am trying to do.

I have a class that is a connection manager for web service connections, like so, (simplified for demo purposes)

```
public class ConnectionManager {

    Webservice webservice = null;

    public Webservice getWebservice() {
        if(webservice == null) {
           synchronize(ConnectionManager.class) {
              if(webservice == null) {
                 webService = new Webservice();
              }
           }
        }
        return webservice;
    }
}
```

I would like to add a process to reset the webservice connection after 30 min of inactivity. I planned on doing this with a Timer and TimerTask since I would only need 1 process to reset the webservice.

```
private class ResetServiceTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        webservice = null;
        logger.warn("resetting the web service connections");
    }
}
```

then to initialize it would look like this:

```
private Timer timer;

public ConnectionManager() {
    timer = new Timer(true);
    timer.schedule(new ResetServiceTimerTask(), 1800000);
}
```

My problem is this, how would I reset the Timer countdown to 0 if a get() method is called? I know I could simply cancel the current timer task and schedule a new one but that seems wasteful.

I've tried looking into executors and thread pools but for some reason I just can't grasp how to properly implement this use case with those. If someone has a good example to link of getting that to work I would gladly take a look at it. From some of the other posts I know that using a thread pool was recommended over using Timer/TimerTask for this.

Comment: I think you need to redesign it, so the 'ConnectionManager ' class will be responsible to setting the 'webservice' instance to null, otherwise, you might get null when calling the 'getWebservice' method.

Comment: @Victor Bouhnik Wouldn't synchronizing on the class and then verifying if the variable is null be sufficient to prevent null returns? I thought it would be similar to examples of how other people do getInstance() calls for singleton classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take the safest solution in the first place: Every time a *get* method is called, cancel the current timerTask and instance a new one, with a new timeout.

Then, you can optimize to save TimerTasks: For example, you can avoid to create a new TimerTask if the next timeout will be *less than one minute* later (or the minimum lapse you decide) than the previous one. I notice your timeout is half an hour (1800000 ms). Then, obviously, precission is not an issue.

It can go like this:

```
private static final int MINIMUM_TIME_LAPSE=60000; // 1 min

private static final int TIMEOUT=1800000; // 30 min

private long previousTime;

private TimerTask timerTask;

private synchronized void scheduleTimeoutIfNecessary()
{
    long currentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (currentTime-this.previousTime >= MINIMUM_TIME_LAPSE)
    {
        if (this.timerTask!=null)
        {
            this.timerTask.cancel();
        }
        this.timerTask=new ResetServiceTimerTask());
        timer.schedule(this.timerTask, TIMEOUT);
        this.previousTime=currentTime;
    }
}
```

BTW: I also recommend you to *synchronize* every access to `webervice`, to avoid run conditions in multithread environments. For that reason, it must be declared private:

```
public class ConnectionManager {

    private Webservice webservice = null;

    public void reset() {
        synchronize(ConnectionManager.class) {
            webService = null;
        }
    }

    public Webservice getWebservice() {
        synchronize(ConnectionManager.class) {
            if(webservice == null) {
               webService = new Webservice();
            }
        }
        return webservice;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks, This actually addresses one of the next issues I was forseeing, which was how to not instantiate/cancel a timer task if the get() methods were called in multithreaded or fast repetition.

Comment: Secondly, the webservice connection is already private. I forgot to include that in my example code. If I mark that variable as volatile would I still have to synchronize the class before checking if it is null or can I do that how I have in my example?

Comment: Tough I have not much experience with volatile variables, I'm afraid _yes_: You'd have to do external synchronization anyway. The reason is to avoid that a second thread sets `webservice` variable to null _just between_ `if (webservice==null)` and `return webservice` is being executed in the first thread.